# Component Interaction causes attempt to use a dehydrated detector exception in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I'm playing around with the component interaction in Angular2.

Stuck with-

> What's the concept of Hydration/dehydration in Angular 2?
>
> How to interact between two components? How to call method of components who are not related(Parent-child/sibling)?

So the code structure is like

I've a AuthApp Component(Powered by Auth0 for Angular2)

```js
 @Output() isUserLoggedIn: EventEmitter<string> =
    new EventEmitter<string>();
```

When user is successfully logged in `isUserLoggedIn` variable will emit true/false value. Like this -

```js
    login() {
        var self = this;
        this.lock.show({}, (err, profile, token) => {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
                return;
            }
            // If authentication is successful, save the items
            // in local storage
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
            this.zoneImpl.run(() => this.user = profile);
            
            this.router.parent.navigate(["Dashboard"]);
//            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            self.isUserLoggedIn.emit("true");
        });
    }
```

In my AppComponent, I'm passing AuthApp component as directive

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './pages/main.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, AuthApp]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: AuthApp, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: AppDashboardComponent },
    { path: '/friends', name: 'Friends', component: AppFriendsComponent }
])
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = "My Space";
    
    @Input() isLoggedIn;

    router: Router;
    
    tokenExpired = tokenNotExpired();

    constructor(router: Router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

I want to capture AuthApp component value in isLoggedIn variable of AppComponent.

isLoggedIn variable in template will show/hide login/logout button.

After the **self.isUserLoggedIn.emit("true");** function is executed I'm facing `Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: HostAuthApp_0 -> isUserLoggedIn`.

Researching this issue got me an idea that the variable is getting out of change detection and hence throwing out the exception but concept is not getting cleared.

Also if anybody can share any active Angular2 community/forum link, any cookbook would be of much help.

Thank You.

Comment: I think EventEmitter is the wrong choice since its for parent-child components. searching some other way..

Comment: You could use a service and inject it into both components? Make sure to provide it at a common point in your component tree. The root component is a good choice unless you have something lower down that makes more sense.